# How can I make it where it will print the longest name/string that was inputed by the user

Tags: python, list, function

```
def myNames():
    names = []
    while True:
        a = input("Enter Name: ")
        if a != "done":
            names.append(a)
        elif a == "done":
            return names

def all_lengths(myNames):
  num_of_strings = len(myNames)
  total_size = 0
  for item in myNames:
     total_size += len(item)
  ave_size = float(total_size) / float(num_of_strings)
  print(ave_size)

all_lengths(myNames())

def longestWord(myNames): 
    count = 0
    for i in myNames:
        if len(i) > count: 
            count = len(i)
            word = I
            print ("the longest string is ", word)
```

how can I make it print the longest name that was inputted by the user for example: out of Samantha and John it would say that Samantha was the longest name

Comment: I need it to count the longest name and display it from the first function without it making me enter names again

Answer (score 0):

```
longestName = ""
for name in myNames:
    if len(name) > len(longestName):
        longestName = name
        
print("The longest name is", longestName)
```

This will check the length of each username, and if the name of that username is longer than the current longest username, it will replace it.

Answer (score 0):

You already have the function for it.
Just need to call the function `longestWord()`.

Write `longestWord(myNames())` at the end of the program. Right after,

```
def longestWord(myNames): 
    count = 0
    for i in myNames:
        if len(i) > count: 
            count = len(i)
            word = i    # Need to type I in lower case
            print ("the longest string is ", word)
```

Update: Since, you don't want the function to ask for names again, you can move the function calling `longestWord()`inside the above function where it calculates average, with the parameter as `myNames` i.e.

```
def myNames():
    names = []
    while True:
        a = input("Enter Name: ")
        if a != "done":
            names.append(a)
        elif a == "done":
            return names

def longestWord(myNames): 
    count = 0
    for i in myNames:
        if len(i) > count: 
            count = len(i)
            word = i
            print ("the longest string is ", word)

def all_lengths(myNames):
  num_of_strings = len(myNames)
  total_size = 0
  for item in myNames:
     total_size += len(item)
  ave_size = float(total_size) / float(num_of_strings)
  print(ave_size)
  longestWord(myNames) # Calling the function with already given names
  
all_lengths(myNames())
```